# asp.net OnButtonClick inside Detailsview hide textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have a `DetailsView` as Popup and there multiple Textbox rows.

All that I need is to find these Text boxes in the c# codebehind.

it should be seems like this.

```
OnButtonClick event
{
    TextBox1.Visible = false/true;
}
```

But I can't get(find Textbox1) the value of `TextBox1` in C# code, thanks for any advises. 
UPD: This is my code (Detailsview is 100% visible truel, Textbox inside EditItemTemplate)

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnHideInfo" runat="server" OnClick="btnHideInfo_Click"/>
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

btnHideInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  TextBox Info1 = dvInvoice.FindControl("txtRechnInfo1") as TextBox;
  TextBox Info2 = dvInvoice.FindControl("txtRechnInfo2") as TextBox; 
  Info1.Visible = false; 
  Info2.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: You can get that by using `FindControl` method, Detailsview1.FindControl("Textview1")` and then typecast to textbox and get value

Comment: Hello, I thought as well as you, but it, some-how, doesnt work...(( here is the code which i tryed protected void `btnHideInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
      `{
        TextBox Info1 = dvInvoice.FindControl("txtRechnInfo1") as TextBox;
        TextBox Info2 = dvInvoice.FindControl("txtRechnInfo2") as TextBox;
        Info1.Visible = false;
        Info2.Visible = false;
        dvInvoice.DataBind();
      }`  maybe did I little mistake somewhere? :)

Comment: Put these content in question , so that others can see and respond. It should work, debug through the application , see if that has content or it has HTMLInput instead of asp Textbox ,or maybe dvInvoice.Visible is  set to false -- some guess from myside.

Comment: added asp and c# code :) And the problem is that i dont get any error, after compile aswell... if i got an error it would be easier to handle with that sh... ((